# Question answered by teachers and students - Database design

Tags: database, class, uml, diagram

I'm designing a database.
I have Question, Answer,Student and Teacher entities
Question asked only by students, but answered by teachers and students, as below:
[image: e]

So an Answer should have only one teacher id or Student id
How can I represent this in class diagram without using inheritance ?

Comment: Just to clarify, the Answer can be provided either by Teacher or by Student and you want to show the answering person but you do not want to create a generalisation class being a superclass of both Student and Teacher. Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: What are you after? You tagged it UML but you want to design a database. It's not contradictonary, but there are different goals. The above is no UML.

Comment: you say *Question asked only by students* and *an Answer should have only one teacher id or seller id* this is contradictory (because *seller* the *id* refers to the person asking the question, not to the person answering). Please clarify your question, also answering to previous remarks, currently it is not possible to help you

Comment: @Ister Yes that's exact

Comment: @qwert_so Yes the above is not UML diagram ijust made for clarification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The requirements of having `Questions` asked by `Student` and related `Answer` provided by either `Student` or `Teacher` could be represented in UML with the help of a [constraint](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/constraint.html?context=class-diagrams):

[image]

So you have in your model 2 possible association for an answer in regard of the answerer: Student and Teacher.  But the constraint tells that for a given answer, only one of the tow is active.  Constraints are expressed between curly brackets.  You can use either natural language (or pseudo-natural language like I did here), or using a more formal and less ambiguous OCL expression.

In a relational database, you could use exactly this scheme, and have for two nullable foreign keys, for example  `ByStudent` and `ByTeacher` and your code would have to make sure that the constraint is respected.

An alternative way to represent this in UML, would be to show with the help of generalization the missing concept:

[image]

This is conceptually more promising.  In relational databases there is however no way to express this directly.  So you'd need to use some table mapping that would end up to be very similar to what is described above, or with an additional [single inheritance table](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) for mapping the `Author`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, tha's what i needed, it was helpful

Comment: I'm not adding my own answer as it would be a replication of this one.